# What happens with the spring controller @SessionAttribute when session get timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a session attribute in my controller @SessionAttribute("sample_dto"). I need to work with the sample_dto even after session get timeout. What is the way to do this properly.

PS: When session get timeout, browser is redirected to login screen. How can I avoid it and bring it back to the place where I was before session get timeout.

Thanks

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem(minimum working example)

Answer (score 11):

According to your question, I think you don't need a session attribute. Because you need to access the same data item in between 
separate sessions. The simplest solution is to use a normal instance variable. Because your controller is singleton in default. 
It is similar to application scope since you don't change the scope of your controller and don't restart your application.

If this task is user specific (your data item should persist per user basis), then you can use cookies for saving the temporary user status. 
In order to set the cookies you can implement your own HttpSessionListener class and within the sessionDestroyed method you can do your cookie saving things.
Because you need to do this thing only when your session is get destroyed(timeout).

If your data is much bigger, then you can save the data in the database by referring to the relevant user. You can use the same sessionDestroyed method.